# (Visual Studio 2015 - 2017) does not create folder (directory) and does not save any value in Properties.settings

Tags: c#

I Test on Visual Studio 2015 - 2017
i was tried more than time to save value in properties.settings.default
or create directory(folder) but visual studio failed

**{only read}**

Please help me

Thanks advance

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying to create the directory? If it's a protected folder (like program files) you need to load Visual Studio with admin rights, or create the projects outside a protected folder (like c:/Projects for example).

It also worth checking if your %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp folder exists and it's not read only. One time I deleted that temp folder and it was recreated automatically as "readonly", making all programs to fail saving anything as they use that temp folder before writing.

Comment: Sorry then, without more info/log I'm unable to help you more

Comment: sorry about that, but i mean , i was tried on drive c , d and e every time failed